# How does Simplify give two answers when they are the same?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am trying to get the CDF of a random variable using TransformedDistribution.

```
Probability[-t v <= y - x <= 
    t v, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, l}], 
    y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, l}]}] // 
 Simplify[#, l > 0 && t > 0 && v > 0 && t v < l] &
```

The result is

$$\left\{ \begin{matrix}
 \frac{t v (2 l-t v)}{l^2} & l\neq 2 t v \\
 \frac{2 t^2 v^2}{l^2}+\frac{1}{4} & l=2 t v \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Why does Simplify give an answer as a separate case when $l=2tv$? If I plug $l=2 tv$ into the first and second answers, they will come to the same result.

Comment: Use `FullSimplify` instead of `Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon FullSimplify gives an answer `Rational[3,4]`, which is the same result if I put `l=2tv` into the first expression above. So the problem remains.

Comment: This is normal, and I'd venture an optimization - using `FullSimplify` indeed gives two cases which are equivalent at `l=2tv`. One requires calculation to resolve, the other doesn't. I'd not want it done another way, particularly when the calc. involved might be time-consuming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the expression using following rewrite rules:

```
Probability[-t v <= y - x <= 
   t v, {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, l}], 
   y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, l}]}] // 
 Assuming[l > 0 && t > 0 && v > 0 && t v < l, 
   Simplify@# //. {HoldPattern@
        Piecewise[{beg___, {a_, acond_}, mid___, {b_, bcond_}, 
          rest___}, default___] /; 
       FullSimplify[a == b, And @@ Not /@ {beg}[[All, 2]] && acond] :>
       FullSimplify@
       Piecewise[{beg, {b, 
          acond || (! acond && And @@ Not /@ {mid}[[All, 2]] && 
             bcond)}, mid, rest}, default],
     HoldPattern@
        Piecewise[{beg___, {a_, acond_}, mid___, {b_, bcond_}, 
          rest___}, default___] /; 
       FullSimplify[a == b, 
        And @@ Not /@ {beg}[[All, 2]] && ! acond && 
         And @@ Not /@ {mid}[[All, 2]] && bcond] :> 
      FullSimplify@
       Piecewise[{beg, {a, 
          acond || (! acond && And @@ Not /@ {mid}[[All, 2]] && 
             bcond)}, mid, rest}, default]}] &
```

This rule rewrites all non-default `Piecewise` regions that `FullSimplify` can pairwise reason to have the same value under their domain to combined regions, and simplifies the resulting expression. (Pedantic reconstruction of condition chain is a bit messy, I admit.) I can't guarantee this works gracefully in general, but on above case the result is clean:

> $$\frac{t v (2 l-t v)}{l^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using `a` in place of `l` for readability

```
pr[a_, t_, v_] = Assuming[
  {a > 0, t > 0, v > 0, t v < a},
  Probability[-t v <= y - x <= t v,
    {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}],
     y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}]}] //
   FullSimplify]

(* Piecewise[{{(t*v*(2*a - t*v))/a^2, a != 2*t*v}}, 
   Rational[3, 4]] *)
```

You can overcome the limitation by either extraction

```
pr[a_, t_, v_] = Assuming[
   {a > 0, t > 0, v > 0, t v < a},
   Probability[-t v <= y - x <= t v,
     {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}],
      y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}]}] //
    FullSimplify][[1, 
   1, 1]]

(* (t*v*(2*a - t*v))/a^2 *)
```

Or by including the additional assumption

```
pr[a_, t_, v_] = Assuming[
  {a > 0, t > 0, v > 0, t v < a, a != 2 t v},
  Probability[-t v <= y - x <= t v,
    {x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}],
     y \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, a}]}] //
   FullSimplify]

(* (t*v*(2*a - t*v))/a^2 *)
```